# Latex font for special expression

Tags: fonts, latex

I want to highlight some special terms throughout my thesis. I do not wanna use tt{} or emph{} or bold to do that but some special font.

Can here somebody suggest me common pratice how to do that in LaTeX?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should be very careful with using more than one font in a text, as it often makes for a messy appearance to mix different fonts. Doing so is very uncommon in scientific texts (I've never seen it), so I would advise you not to do it. Why can't you use the regular highlighting mechanisms?

That said, you can switch fonts using `\fontfamily{family}`, where family is the family name of an installed font. See the [LaTeX help](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/latex/latex2e.html#SEC178) for details on switching fonts ("typefaces" in LaTeX).

You may need to install an additional to use it for highlighting. How to do that will depend on the LaTeX system you use. See e.g. [the CTAN docs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/) for various hints on how to do this.